# Linux filezilla cannot connect however there is no issue on windows

Tags: ssh, sftp, filezilla

I am trying to connect to my server using secrue ftp (SFTP).

On Windows I have no problem however on my Linux computer I get the following error:

```
status: Connecting to 89.104.207.220...
Response:   fzSftp started
Command:    open "root@89.104.207.220" 22
Error:  No route to host
Error:  Could not connect to server
Status: Waiting to retry...
Status: Connecting to 89.104.207.220...
Response:   fzSftp started
Command:    open "root@89.104.207.220" 22
Error:  No route to host
Error:  Could not connect to server
Status: Connecting to 89.104.207.220...
Response:   fzSftp started
Command:    open "root@89.104.207.220" 22
Error:  No route to host
Error:  Could not connect to server
Status: Waiting to retry...
Status: Connecting to 89.104.207.220...
Response:   fzSftp started
Command:    open "root@89.104.207.220" 22
Error:  No route to host
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

I have opened port 22 using the following command:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

However nothing happened.

has anyone tried this and know how to fix it?

Comment: You don't need to open port 22 on your Linux installation in INPUT since your are connecting out of your box. Can you ping 89.104.207.220 and/or browse the internet?

Comment: @unlink i can connect using the console on ssh

Comment: @unlink i have also opened the port on the server

Comment: Can you connect to the server using "sftp 89.104.207.220"? Are you sure you specified the hostname correctly in Filezilla?

Comment: Did you login with: Sftp://your_host ??

Comment: So if you do `ssh 89.104.207.220` on the same machine you run FileZilla, it connects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> open "root@89.104.207.220" 22

It sure looks to me like you put the `root@` as part of the server address and it is trying to connect to the host literally named `root@89.104.207.220`, not as root to the host named `89.104.207.220`.  Double check your input.

Comment: FileZilla logs PSFTP commands it issues to an underlying PSFTP process. And the `open username@hostname port` is a correct syntax the PSFTP accepts. See http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.63/htmldoc/Chapter6.html#psftp-cmd-open